# Structure an object using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

Given the object data I wish to recursively structure it so it looks like structuredObj. I have s1 through to sN. I've only defined s2 to get started.

This is the input:

```
                    var data {   
                        ...

                       "s2": true,
                       "s2a": true,
                       "s2b": true,
                       "s2c": true,
                       "s2d": true,
                       "s2e": true,
                       "s2f": true,
                       "s2fa": true,
                       "s2fb": false,
                       "s2g": true,
                       "s2h": true,
                       "s2ha": false,
                       "s2hb": true,
                       "s2i": true,
                       "s2ia": false,
                       "s2j": true,
                       "s2k": true,
                       "s2l": true,
                       "s2m": true,
                       "s2n": true,
                       "s2o": true

                        ...
                    }
```

This is the output:

```
var structuredObj = {
            "s2": {
            "situation": "The client owns a property.",
                "a": true,
                "questions": {
                "a": {
                    "q": "A.  Does the court order permit the deputy to sell the property?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "b": {
                    "q": "B.  Is the client a resident in the property?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "c": {
                    "q": "C.  Is the spouse of the client a resident in the property?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "d": {
                    "q": "D.  Is a dependant of the client a resident in the property?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "e": {
                    "q": "E.  Is the property being maintained?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "f": {
                    "q": "F.  Is the property being rented out?",
                        "a": true,
                        "questions": {
                        "a": {
                            "q": "a)  Is an appropriate income being received?",
                                "a": true
                        },
                        "b": {
                            "q": "b)  Is there a rental agreement in place?",
                                "a": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "g": {
                    "q": "G.  Is there an appropriate insurance policy in place?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "h": {
                    "q": "H.  Does the client have any valuables in the property?",
                        "a": true,
                        "questions": {
                        "a": {
                            "q": "a)  Are the valuables secure?",
                                "a": false
                        },
                        "b": {
                            "q": "b)  Have details of the valuable been reported to the OPG?",
                                "a": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "i": {
                    "q": "I.  Does the client require care?",
                        "a": true,
                        "questions": {
                        "a": {
                            "q": "a)  Are the client’s care costs being met?",
                                "a": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "j": {
                    "q": "J.  Is there a charge against the property?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "k": {
                    "q": "K.  Is the deputy considering selling the property?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "l": {
                    "q": "L.  Is the property jointly owned?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "m": {
                    "q": "M.  Has the Deputy been asked to take action previously?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "n": {
                    "q": "N.  Is there a history of risk on the case?",
                        "a": true
                },
                "o": {
                    "q": "O.  Have any other risks to the client been identified?",
                        "a": true
                }
            }
        }



                    // Something like this:
                    structuredObj = structureMyFlatObject(data);
```

This is the function that takes the input and structures it.

```
            structureData: function (data) {

                var i=0,
                    situationNum,
                    previousSituationLetter,
                    situationLetter,
                    situationalChildLetter,
                    label = 'LABEL.NAME',
                    structuredObj = {},
                    keys = Object.keys(data);

                for(; i<keys.length; i++) {

                    situationNum = keys[i].substring(0,2); // s1 - s28
                    situationLetter = keys[i].charAt(2);   // a - z

                    if(keys[i].length === 4) {

                        situationalChildLetter = keys[i].charAt(3); // a - z

                        if(!structuredObj[situationNum].questions[previousSituationLetter].questions) {
                            structuredObj[situationNum].questions[previousSituationLetter].questions = {};
                        }

                        structuredObj[situationNum].questions[previousSituationLetter].questions[situationalChildLetter] = {
                            "q": $translate.instant(label + keys[i].toUpperCase()),
                            "a": data[keys[i]]
                        };

                        continue;
                    }

                    //Does the property start with s1, s2, s3, .., .., s28
                    if(keys[i].indexOf(situationNum) === 0 ) {

                        if(structuredObj[situationNum]) {
                            structuredObj[situationNum].questions[situationLetter] = {
                                "q": $translate.instant(label + keys[i].toUpperCase()),
                                "a": data[keys[i]]
                            };
                        } else {
                            structuredObj[situationNum] = {};
                            structuredObj[situationNum].situation = $translate.instant(label + keys[i].toUpperCase());
                            structuredObj[situationNum].a = data[keys[i]];
                            structuredObj[situationNum].questions = {};
                        }
                    }

                    previousSituationLetter = situationLetter;
                }

                return structuredObj;
            },
```

This works for this particular use case but I need it to work for all e.g s1-s28. Currently this function blows up when hitting s10fa for example. I was hoping for a recursive solution as it's starting to get messy.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you managed to write, otherwise we won't be able to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for a binary tree like structure but instead only two nodes, have x-amount of iterable node and just iterate over each one, and do somthing to determine if it's going to be a question or a new object of self.

Edit: I meant like this:

```js
var max_depth = 4;
    var current_depth = 0;

    function n(){
      return {};
    }

    function random_object(obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
          temp = {};
          var end = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
          for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            temp[String(i)] = null;
          }
          return temp;

        } else {
          for (var key in obj) {
              if((Math.random() * 10) < 5){
               obj[key] = "This is element " + key + " of depth " +    current_depth
              }else{
                if( current_depth < max_depth){
                  current_depth = current_depth + 1
                  obj[key] = random_object(random_object());
                }else{
                  obj[key] = "This is element " + key + " of depth " +     (current_depth + 1)
                }
              }
            }
            current_depth = current_depth - 1
            return obj;
        }
    }
    console.log(random_object(random_object()));
```

it recursively generates an object of random x-amount of attributes which each can either be a string (a question) or another object of random x-amount of attributes

Comment: No, it has to be written in javascript,  converted to json and then over the wire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, you haven't really answered my question. The input has to be data (like I posted) I have no control over this. Again, the structure has to look like what I've posted. There is no in between. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not doing your work for you, I'm showing an example of using a recursive function to build an object. You need to work out how to format the  data and recursively build it into an object. I'll give you a hint, you need to work out where the if statement that only has two possible responses happens; one that either sets a value or one that leads to the function recursively being called that returns an object. The object in your example however has no consistency (both "questions" and "f" are nested objects"), so I can't actually judge what will place a value and what will call the function.

Comment: Obviously I don't expect you to do the work for me, I'm sorry if that's the way I came across. I've given more information above so hope that helps.